# How to list "unavailable packages" in packageStatus()?

Tags: r

As example, I would like to list which these 7 "unavailable" packages are, how should I do?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Note that packageStatus() compares your packages to CRAN (or whatever repo you are pointing to). If you installed packages from github or directly from a tar ball, then they will be reported as unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `packageStatus()` [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/packageStatus.html) note, it returns a list with two components. The one we're interested in is `inst`:

> a data frame with columns as the matrix returned by `installed.packages` plus `"Status"`, a factor with `levels c("ok", "upgrade", "unavailable")`.

Here's a function to extract it:

```r
get_packages_with_status <- function(status = "unavailable", names_only = TRUE, ...) {
    pkgs <- packageStatus(...)
    tbl <- pkgs$inst[pkgs$inst$Status == status, ]
    if (names_only) {
        return(unname(tbl$Package))
    }
    tbl
}
```

The output should be something like:

```r
get_packages_with_status()
#  [1] "assertive"            "assertive.code"       "assertive.data"       "assertive.data.uk"    "assertive.data.us"    "assertive.datetimes" 
#  [7] "assertive.properties" "assertive.reflection" "assertive.strings"    "assertive.types"      "BiocGenerics"         "BiocVersion"         
# [13] "cqcapi"               "cqcrequests"          "echarts4r.maps"       "estimability"         "geojsonlint"          "getnews"             
# [19] "graph"                "hexjsonwidget"        "maptools"             "optiRum"              "pwrcalc"              "rgdal"
```

Of if you want the full data frame.

```
get_packages_with_status(names_only = FALSE)
#                                   Package                                     LibPath    Version Priority                                         Depends
# assertive                       assertive /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.3-6     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.code             assertive.code /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-3     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.data             assertive.data /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-3     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.data.uk       assertive.data.uk /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-2     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.data.us       assertive.data.us /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-2     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.datetimes   assertive.datetimes /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-3     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.properties assertive.properties /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-5     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# assertive.reflection assertive.reflection /home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2      0.0-5     <NA>                                    R (>= 3.0.0)
# <etc>
```

Note also the definition of available depends on what you supply as the argument to `repositories`:

> a character vector of URLs describing the location of R package repositories on the Internet or on the local machine. If specified as NULL, derive appropriate URLs from option `"repos"`.

This is why, as noted by MrFlick's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78108702/how-to-list-unavailable-packages-in-packagestatus/78108741#comment137702549_78108702), in my list I can see packages listed as unavailable even though I know they're installed, because they were installed from GitHub or locally.